# $scope.$on getting different values than sent by $scope$.emit

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I'm trying to sent the moment which is the first date of the month through $scope.$emit from directive. But $scope.$on in parent controller getting the end date.

```
 $scope.$emit('sample',$scope.month, $element)
```

Here I'm sending the moment object which is first date of the month (08-01-2016).

```
 $scope.$on('sample', function(event, month, element) { }
```

Here it is receiving the end date of the month.

Is it related to scope issues?

UPDATE:

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgxdb.png) is the screenshot of month object in $scope.$on function

Comment: moments are mutable so maybe you are changing it somewhere else. No way to tell from the code you showed though. Can you reproduce it in a plunker?

Comment: @gopi is this `$scope.month` moment object or  first date? I would recommend you to use ``$scope.$emit('sample', {month : $scope.month, element: $element }) ``

```$scope.$on('sample', function(event, data) { 
//data.month
//data.element
});```

Comment: @MohanSingh $scope.month is moment object

Comment: @gopi Did you find the solution?